# DevExpress Scheduler for Mvc - Get selected interval

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, devexpress, scheduler

I'm developping a web app using the DevExpress Scheduler control for MVC. I have a page which displays my scheduler in day view mode. What I want to do is, when I click on a button (for instance, 'new appointment'), I can get the values (in DateTime format?) of the time interval I've selected in my scheduler.

I've read that I've to use the ASPxClientScheduler to do that but I'm working with MVC. Is there any solution for that type of application?

Answer (score 0):

You can obtain in instance of the [MVCxClientScheduler](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/clsDevExpressWebMVCScriptsMVCxClientSchedulertopic) by its name that equals the value assigned to the [SchedulerSettings.Name](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebMvcSettingsBase_Nametopic) property.

The similar question was answered on DevExpress forum: [How to use instance of MVCxClientScheduler class in client javascript to get value from GetSelectedInterval() method](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q497927)

Comment: That's nearly what I expected so first thank you ! However, I need these values in order to pass them to my controller Action (which needs 2 DateTime parameters). Is it possible?

Comment: You can execute it using the jQuery.ajax method.